# Can I run typescript code with ts-node and declared js-module?

Tags: typescript

Story:

1. :) developing typescript application while using nodemon with ts-node
2. :/ realizing library I need to use has no types (asterisk-manager)
3. :( being unable to run this library with setup and knowledge I have

How can I declare this library so I can run my application with ts-node and nodemon again ?
link to library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/asterisk-manager

Comment: `declare module asterisk-manager`

Comment: Hi Roberto, how can I do so ?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to [@Roberto Zvjerković](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7436489/roberto-zvjerkovi%C4%87) for sharing knowledge.

To anyone who feels stuck as me this is [great start](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules).

I have created asterisk-manager.d.ts file and add some configuration:

`src/connectors/asterisk/asterisk-manager.d.ts`

```js
declare module 'asterisk-manager' {
    function keepConnected(): any
    export interface ManagerResult {
        keepConnected: keepConnected
    }
    export default function Manager(
        port: string,
        host: string,
        username: string,
        password: string,
        events: unknown
    ): ManagerResult
}
```

Now I can import asterisk-manager as follows:

`src/connectors/asterisk/connector.ts`

```js
import Manager from 'asterisk-manager'
```